# If statement is being short-circuited by some misplaced code - Why?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain, why this code prints "whats going on?"

```
if(x=21) 342423 
  console.log('whats going on?')
```

I had accidentally typed a number next to an if conditional statement, like the above in a program. It was causing a weird side effect that the conditional statement was being short circuited, even if the stuff in the brackets evaluated to false. The annoying thing was it wasn't throwing an interpreter error.

Comment: why, what is the problem with it? Its a serious question, that doesn't deserve such a childish response.

Comment: please use { } to define a block of code to be executed if the condition is true...

Comment: djechlin, You are making an assumption there.
zoran404, that doesnt explain why it doesnt throw an error, or why it prints the message.

Comment: `if` can be followed by any valid _expression_ – and `342423` in itself already is exactly that, an expression. (And always using curly brackets after if/else is recommended for a reason.)

Comment: Please take the time to read up basic Javascript syntax and functionality, that will answer your problem.

Comment: @Cbroe thanks very much! that explains it, unlike the other unhelpful comments i received.

Comment: telling people to read a book could be the answer to 90% of the questions on this site, not very helpful to be honest.

Comment: without reading a book it's not hard to use basic tools like browser console and code linters to do basic troubleshooting

Comment: I did use the console to try and figure out what was going on, but couldn't, hence my question in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's essentially two ways to write conditional statements in Javascript (leaving aside ternary):
With curly braces:

```
if (condition) {
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
```

...or without curlies:

```
if (condition)
    foo();
else
    bar();
```

The second option, however can only be used if you have single statements, not a more complex logic.
Without the `else`, the second sample functions as

```
if (condition)
     foo();
//Other code follows, regardless of how the condition resolves
console.log("This is always shown");
```

The above is also what your question is about:

```
if(x=21)
    342423
console.log('whats going on?')
```

You've simply indented your code differently, possibly leading to your confusion.
`342423` is a valid statement in Javascript, just like `foo()`, leading to your `console.log()` being executed regardless of the condition.
The missing semicolon is added automagically by the script parser.
Also, note that `x = 21`, `x == 21` and `x === 21` are *very* different things in Javascript, you can look them up in other answers on this site.

Comment: thanks nit! the bit of the puzzle i was missing was "the missing semi colon is added automagically by the script parser"